# Shapely area of self-intersecting polygon

Tags: polygon, area, shapely

I am trying to calculate area between two curves. One is diagonal straight line and the other is arbitrary curve. The curves intersect so I cannot just take an area under one curve and subtract the area under the other curve. Each of my curves include 10 points, so I created a Shapely polygon by joining the coordinate points of the first curve (in ascending order of x) with coordinate points of the second curve (in descending order of x) and then added the first point of the first curve to enclose the polygon. When I plot the polygon and the curves, the polygon shapes are correct (see the examples), however the areas of the polygons, calculated with `Polygon(polygon_points).area` are not correct. For the first polygon, the output is ~0.024, whereas for the second, the output is ~0.008, even though we can easily see that the areas are much more close in value. Also, the area of the full graph is ~1 (1 times 1), so just by eyeballing the plots, we can see that the blue areas represent more than what the ouput gives.

I am thinking that Shapely might calculating the area of first part of a polygon positively, and the second part (after intersection) negatively. Am I correct?

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw29x.png)
[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynZLe.png)

Comment: It would be easier if you posted a small script with the relevant polygon in it so it is possible to test it, but the first thing I would try is to call [shapely.make_valid](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.make_valid.html#shapely.make_valid) on the polygon before calculating the area.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to split polygon into separate non-intersecting polygons and calculate each area separately.

```
from shapely.ops import polygonize
    # split into multiple, non-intersecting polygons
    p_exterior = polygon.exterior
    mls = p_exterior.intersection(p_exterior)
    polygons = polygonize(mls)
    poly_area = []
    for poly in polygons:
        poly_area.append(poly.area)
    print('Area:',np.sum(poly_area))
```